# Arrow in table from line to line with text

Tags: tables, arrows, gauss

I have the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    95\celsius & 3 min \\ \hline
    98\celsius & 10 sec \\ \hline
    55\celsius & 10 sec \\ \hline
    72\celsius & 1 min \\ \hline
    72\celsius & 10 min \\ \hline
    8\celsius & hold \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

How can I draw an arrow from one line to another with some text on it? (Similar to how it can be done in a gmatrix from the gauss package.)

The arrow should look somewhat like this:
[image: arrow]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be something that can be done with the `tikzmark` library. Notice that your LaTeX code does not really produce the table shown on the screen shot, so I had to improvise a bit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \si{95\celsius} & 3 min \\ \hline
    \si{98\celsius} & 10 sec\hfill\tikzmark{A} \\ \hline
    \si{55\celsius} & 10 sec \\ \hline
    \si{72\celsius} & 1 min\hfill\tikzmark{B} \\ \hline
    \si{72\celsius} & 10 min \\ \hline
    \si{8\celsius} & hold \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[thick,-latex] ([yshift=3pt]pic cs:B) -| ([xshift=1cm,yshift=3pt]pic cs:A) 
node[pos=0.75,right] {30 mal} --([yshift=3pt]pic cs:A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great. Do You have an idea how I could move the arrow just a tad more to the side, so that it is fully outside of the table?

Comment: @dYTe Yes, sure, just add some `xshift` to the points, e.g. `\draw[thick,-latex] ([xshift=2mm,yshift=3pt]pic cs:B) -| ([xshift=1cm,yshift=3pt]pic cs:A) 
node[pos=0.75,right] {30 mal} --([xshift=2mm,yshift=3pt]pic cs:A);`.